How do I pass an ArrayList from one method to another in Java?
I need to create an empty list in one method and save the reference. Then, I need to pass the reference to another method where the list is populated with shapes and their parameters.

public class Test {
public static void start() {
    ArrayList<Object> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static void create() {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataFile.txt"));
    
    if (file.readLine() == "Rectangle") {
        String shapeType = file.readLine();
        String name = file.readLine();
        Double length = Double.valueOf(file.readLine());
        Double width = Double.valueOf(file.readLine());
        Rectangle newShape = new Shape.Rectangle(name, length, width);
        shapes.add(newShape); // this is where this class cannot recognize "shapes" list




You can't, not with that design.
start() makes a list, saves the ref in its shapes local variable, and then.. tosses that variable into the garbage. That object is made and becomes instantaneous garbage.
You can either return that list and then pass it to create:
public static List<Shape> start() {
  return new ArrayList<Shape>();
}

public static void create(List<Shape> shapes) {
  ...
}

Or more likely, static is not something you should be using. Generally if someone is learning java and starts sprinkling static everywhere, it's not going well. You should not use it for.. a year. Yeah, main has to be, so, make your main method a one liner: new MainClass().go() - now you're 'out' of static and can stop using it entirely.
Thus:
public class ShapesProcessor {
  private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

  public void create() {
    ... code here - shapes is available ...
  }
}

Note that we don't do 'start' methods in java, we use constructors. The above code has an implicit one; creating a new ShapesProcessor() 'starts' (makes a list and assigns its reference to a field) automatically.

If you use the latest version of Java with --enable-preview even main doesn't have to be static. :)
